# Using any action in YAML file throws not found error in VS Code, but it's ok in GitHub actions

Tags: typescript, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm writhing YAML file in my workflow and using any action get red underlined in VS Code and throw error that repo or version is not found, but file is ok and working on GitHub actions

```
name: ci

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - main
            - master
    pull_request:
        branches:
            - main
            - master

jobs:
    ci:
        runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

        strategy:
            matrix:
                os: [ubuntu-latest]
                node: [20]

        steps:
            - name: Checkout
              uses: actions/checkout@master

            - name: Setup node env
              uses: actions/setup-node@v2.1.2
              with:
                  node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}

            - name: Cache node_modules
              uses: actions/cache@v2
              with:
                  path: ~/.npm
                  key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
                  restore-keys: |
                      ${{ runner.os }}-node-

            - name: Install dependencies
              run: npm ci

            - name: Run code style check
              run: npm run style:all

            - name: Run tests
              run: npm run test
```

Error that shown:

```
    Unable to resolve action `actions/cache@v2`, repository or version not found
```

I have tried changing @v versions or writing action on my own, but problem was not solved

i recognized that github action vscode extention is the root of problem for having connectivity problems , i can't fix internet problem because my location using vpn and tunneling whole pc didn't fix it , github action extenstion simply refuse to connect to my account and work

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: You forgot to mention what extension you're using which causes the errors.

Comment: It's not really an error. Just a warning that it can't give you auto completion for the action as it can't download the action.yaml.

Answer (score -4):

If you are encountering issues with YAML files in Visual Studio Code (VS Code) but not in GitHub Actions, there could be a few reasons for this discrepancy. Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:

1. **Check VS Code YAML Extension:**
   Ensure that you have a YAML extension installed and enabled in VS Code. There are several YAML extensions available, and they can provide syntax highlighting and validation for YAML files. Popular ones include "YAML" by Red Hat and "YAML Language Support" by Red Hat.
2. **YAML Linting:**
   Make sure your YAML file is correctly formatted. YAML is indentation-sensitive, and even small indentation errors can lead to parsing issues. Use a YAML linter to check for syntax errors. You can find online YAML linters or use the integrated linters provided by some YAML extensions in VS Code.
3. **VS Code Version:**
   Ensure that you are using the latest version of VS Code. Extensions and their functionalities can sometimes depend on the version of the editor.
4. **Extension Conflicts:**
   Disable other extensions to check if there is a conflict causing the issue. Sometimes, multiple extensions might not work well together.
5. **GitHub Actions Extension:**
   If you have the "GitHub Actions" extension installed, check if there is any issue or update available for that extension. Extensions can sometimes cause conflicts with each other.
6. **Workspace Settings:**
   Check your workspace settings in VS Code. There might be specific settings affecting YAML file validation. Open the settings (`Ctrl` + `,`), and search for any YAML-related settings.
7. **GitHub Actions Schema:**
   GitHub Actions use a specific schema for their YAML files. Ensure that your YAML file adheres to the GitHub Actions schema. You can refer to the official GitHub Actions documentation for guidance on the correct structure and syntax.
8. **VS Code YAML Validation:**
   VS Code might have its own YAML validation that could be different from GitHub Actions. If there are specific actions that are causing issues, try to simplify the YAML file, removing unnecessary parts, and gradually add them back to identify the problematic section.
9. **Restart VS Code:**
   Sometimes, restarting VS Code can resolve intermittent extension issues.

If you've tried these steps and are still facing issues, please provide more specific details about the error messages or the part of the YAML file causing problems.

Comment: Sounds like AI generated